# Random sampling, need some help and guides

Tags: sampling

i was asked to do an assignment on examining the Body Mass index of students. I have to select at least 50 students from my school, and i was asked to describe how I ensure the randomness of the sample. Can anyone explain to me how can i ensure the randomness of my samples?

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you would put all the students in your school into a numbered list ($1, 2, ..., N$).  Then, using a random number generator (or a list of random numbers), you would pick $50$ random numbers from $1$ to $N$, and use the corresponding students on the list for your sample.

Comment: Because my teacher knew that i wasnt doing that way. Can i say that i recorded 80 students' BMI from three classes and i use the number generator to select 50 from the 80????

Comment: That would be a random sample of the $80$ students in the three classes, but not a random sample from the whole school.  I guess ultimately it would be up to your teacher to decide if that was suitable.